# How to create a Cordova plugin for Android with obfuscated code?

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, obfuscation

I'm building a Cordova plugin that needs to be obfuscated before it is imported in the Cordova Android app. Similar to the [mpay plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/com.infobip.mpay).

The cordova plugin [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) for Android explains how to write a plugin that gets compiled together with the Android app. However, how should one compile, jar, obfuscate and package a plugin to distribute witout source ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You isolate the code you want to obfuscate in a jar, and put it with the source code for the Cordova plugin you're creating (under src).

Then you mention the jar in the **plugin.xml** file with **<lib-file src="src/path_to_jar"/>** so that Cordova knows it should treat the file as library when packaging the code.

This is how the **mpay** developers did it.
They put the jar [here](https://github.com/infobip/payment-plugin-sencha/tree/master/cordova/plugins/com.infobip.mpay/src/android)
and mentioned it [here](https://github.com/infobip/payment-plugin-sencha/blob/master/cordova/plugins/com.infobip.mpay/plugin.xml#L26).